# POSTGRESQL - PROBLEMA INSERT CON LEFT JOIN Y CASE

Tags: postgresql, insert

Tengo esta regla INSERT a una tabla maquinaria con los campos id_proto_periodo y coste_hora_aplicado, que coge los valores de un select a otra tabla a traves de un CASE, la cual quiero modificar para que según el valor que se inserta en la tabla maquinaria, se inserte un valor u otro en el coste hora.

El insert es el siguiente.

```
INSERT INTO pro.proto_maquinaria(                                           --TABLA DONDE SE INSERTAN LOS DATOS
                    id_proto_periodo, coste_hora_aplicado,
                )
                SELECT
                    new.id_proto_periodo,
                            CASE WHEN **t_p.id_tarifa_proto = 1** THEN (    -- VALOR DE TARIFA de proto_periodo
                                t.tarifa_power 
                                )ELSE (                         
                                t.tarifa_power2 
                                ) END
                FROM navh.proc_centro_trabajo__vista AS t                   -- TABLA DE DONDE SE COGEN LOS PRECIOS

                **JOIN pro.proto_periodo__vista AS t_p ON t_p.id = new.id_proto_periodo; -- QUIERO SABER EL VALOR DE id_tarifa_proto de proto_periodo segun el valor de new.id_proto_periodo PARA QUE EL CASE INSERTE UN VALOR U OTRO.**
```

**Los * es donde tengo el problema.**

En proc.centro_trabajo_vista no tengo id_proto_periodo. id_proto_periodo lo voy a insertar en maquinaria__vista (new.id_proto_periodo).
El error es:

**JOIN pro.proto_periodo__vista AS t_p ON t_p.id = new.id_pro... 
                                                              ^ 
HINT:  There is an entry for table "new", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.**

No se me ocurre como hacerlo sin trigger after insert, me vendria mucho mejor si se pudiera asi. Gracias.

Comment: Si le quito el new, para que haga referencia a id_proto_periodo de la tabla maquinaria, aparece este error:

There is a column named "id_proto_periodo" in table "proto_maquinaria", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.  

Como lo referencio correctamente al id_proto_periodo de la tabla donde se va a insertar (maquinaria) en ved proc_centro_trabajo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente como no consegui hacerlo mediante leftjoin, lo he hecho mediante subconsulta quedando:

```
INSERT INTO pro.proto_maquinaria(                                           
                    id_proto_periodo, coste_hora_aplicado,
                )
                SELECT
                    new.id_proto_periodo,
                            CASE WHEN ((SELECT id_tarifa_proto FROM pro.proto_periodo__vista WHERE id = new.id_proto_periodo)= 1) THEN (               
                                t.tarifa_power 
                                )ELSE (                         
                                t.tarifa_power2
                                ) END
                FROM navh.proc_centro_trabajo__vista AS t
```

gracias por la ayuda, me empeñe en hacerlo con left join sin tener referencia.